# Linear transformation and derivative

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, linear-transformations

Let $f:\mathbb R^n \rightarrow \mathbb R^m$ be linear. Find $D^2f(\mathbf x_0)$.

I do not really know how to start from here. We are not given any more details to solve the derivative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: What is the (very familiar) form of $f(x)$ if $n = m = 1$? In that case, what's the second derivative?

Comment: Just $f''(x_0)$?

Comment: What about my first question? What is $f(x)$ for the $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ case?

Comment: ok, so the second derivative should be 0

Comment: Right, so it needs to be justified for the vector case. You can, for example, explicitly differentiate the linear map $f$ twice by first writing down a matrix expression for $f$, then applying the limit definition of the derivative twice.

Comment: what do you mean by "explicitly"? I don't think I've learnt that before

Comment: I've added further explanation to my above comment.

Comment: ok, though I do not understand, but how to apply the condition that $f$ is linear?

Comment: Well, how did you answer the questions posed in my hint? You'll use the same methodology for the general case.

Comment: dude, I really don't understand you.

Comment: You told me that the second derivative is 0. How did you come to that conclusion?

Comment: f=c, f'=0, f''=0

Comment: $f = c$ would indicate that $f$ is a constant function. For $n = m = 1$, $f(x)$ being linear means that $f(x) = ax$ for some number $a$.

Comment: for $n\ne 1$ and $m\ne 1$?

Comment: To answer that, you need to use the underlying definition of a linear function. In particular, it is useful to understand that every linear function between Euclidean spaces can be represented by a matrix.

Comment: I'm thinking about another way: we know the fact that $D^2f(x_0)(v,w)=\partial_v\partial_w f(x_0)$. Then since $f$ is linear, $Df(x_0)(v)=f(v)$. So $D^2f(x_0)(v,w) = Df(w)(v)$. Is that right?

Comment: Your expression $Df(x_0)(v) = f(v)$ is good. Differentiating again, however, requires you to pay attention to which variable you're differentiating with respect to. Just putting another $D$ in front is not generally valid. In particular, the expression $Df(w)(v)$ is not well-defined $Df$ needs to be evaluated at some point $x$. I really encourage you to understand why the scalar case and the vector case are very similar, if not essentially the same.

Comment: If you need a final hint, you have $Df(x)(v) = f(v)$. This implies the first derivative is constant in $x$. Since you're differentiating with respect to $x$, then taking the derivative once more will yield the zero map.